# libigl not found when "cmake" to libigl on amazon linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, amazon-linux, libigl

I tried install **libigl**. Although in [this tutorial](https://libigl.github.io/#installation), it says that it does not need installation, my program not found the libraries.

In my local machine with Ubuntu, cmake works fine!

But in Amazon Linux, instance of EC2 not working.

I compile my project with:

```
cmake3 .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/out
```

And the Error is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (message):
  libigl not found --- You can download it using:

   git clone --recursive https://github.com/libigl/libigl.git /home/ec2-user/closer-lambda/../libigl
```

*closer-lamba* is the folder of my c++ project

I tried with git clone, and copy paste library from my original project in Ubuntu to Amazon Linux (to into folder project, ec2-user folder, etc), but always I receive the same error.

My CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include_directories(includes)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(closer LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(aws-lambda-runtime REQUIRED)
find_package(AWSSDK COMPONENTS s3)

#LIBIGL

#LIBIGL
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(LIBIGL QUIET)

if (NOT LIBIGL_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libigl not found --- You can download it using: \n git clone --recursive https://github.com/libigl/libigl.git ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libigl")
endif()

# Compilation flags: adapt to your needs
if(MSVC)
    # Enable parallel compilation
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP /bigobj")
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
else()
    # Libigl requires a modern C++ compiler that supports c++11
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "." )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-deprecated-declarations")
endif()



# libigl options: choose between header only and compiled static library
# Header-only is preferred for small projects. For larger projects the static build
# considerably reduces the compilation times
option(LIBIGL_USE_STATIC_LIBRARY "Use LibIGL as static library" OFF)

# add a customizable menu bar
option(LIBIGL_WITH_NANOGUI     "Use Nanogui menu"   OFF)

# libigl options: choose your dependencies (by default everything is OFF except opengl)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_VIEWER      "Use OpenGL viewer"  OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_OPENGL      "Use OpenGL"         ON)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_OPENGL_GLFW "Use GLFW"           ON)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_BBW         "Use BBW"            OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_EMBREE      "Use Embree"         OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_PNG         "Use PNG"            OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_TETGEN      "Use Tetgen"         OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_TRIANGLE    "Use Triangle"       ON)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_XML         "Use XML"            OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_LIM         "Use LIM"            OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_COMISO      "Use CoMiso"         OFF)
option(LIBIGL_WITH_MATLAB      "Use Matlab"         OFF) # This option is not supported yet
option(LIBIGL_WITH_MOSEK       "Use MOSEK"          OFF) # This option is not supported yet
option(LIBIGL_WITH_CGAL        "Use CGAL"           OFF)
if(LIBIGL_WITH_CGAL) # Do not remove or move this block, the cgal build system fails without it
    find_package(CGAL REQUIRED)
    set(CGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS TRUE CACHE BOOL "CGAL's CMAKE Setup is super annoying ")
    include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})
endif()

# Adding libigl: choose the path to your local copy libigl
# This is going to compile everything you requested
#message(FATAL_ERROR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libigl/cmake")
add_subdirectory("${LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/../shared/cmake" "libigl")

# libigl information
message("libigl includes: ${LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("libigl libraries: ${LIBIGL_LIBRARIES}")
message("libigl extra sources: ${LIBIGL_EXTRA_SOURCES}")
message("libigl extra libraries: ${LIBIGL_EXTRA_LIBRARIES}")
message("libigl definitions: ${LIBIGL_DEFINITIONS}")

#END LIBIGL


# Prepare the build environment
include_directories(${LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LIBIGL_DEFINITIONS})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" ${LIBIGL_EXTRA_SOURCES} Colorizer.h Colorizer.cpp EdgeLeveler.cpp EdgeLeveler.h SawToothCleaner.cpp SawToothCleaner.h Utilities.cpp Utilities.h)  
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                      AWS::aws-lambda-runtime
                       ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES}
                        ${LIBIGL_LIBRARIES} 
                         ${LIBIGL_EXTRA_LIBRARIES})

aws_lambda_package_target(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

I think to should compile libigl, but i tried and library blas not found.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

I forget copy the "cmake" folder, its contain:

"FindLIBIGL.cmake" in my case, libigl is in logal_libigl

```
 # - Try to find the LIBIGL library
# Once done this will define
#
#  LIBIGL_FOUND - system has LIBIGL
#  LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR - **the** LIBIGL include directory
#  LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIRS - LIBIGL include directories
#  LIBIGL_SOURCES - the LIBIGL source files
if(NOT LIBIGL_FOUND)

    FIND_PATH(LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR igl/readOBJ.h
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/local_libigl/libigl
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/local_libigl/libigl/include
            )


    if(LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
        set(LIBIGL_FOUND TRUE)
        set(LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR}  ${LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/../external/Singular_Value_Decomposition)
        #set(LIBIGL_SOURCES
        #   ${LIBIGL_INCLUDE_DIR}/igl/viewer/Viewer.cpp
        #)
    endif()

endif()
```